# YUI Popup Background

Tags: javascript, yui

I am using YUI popus at multiple places in my project. For which i have given a body background color #fff in common css. But in one popup i don't want this popup background. How can i remove this from javascript.

```
notifier : new function(){
var n = new YAHOO.widget.Panel("indicator", {
                    width:"200px",  
        x:450,
        y:70,
        fixedCenter:true,
        close:false,  
        draggable:false,  
        zindex:4, 
        modal:true, 
        visible:false 
    }); 

    n.setBody("<img src='"+imagePath+"/loadingBig.gif'/>"+customerMsg.loading+"..."); 

    n.render(document.body); 

}
```

I want to change body background for this popup.

Answer (score 0):

For a single particular instance change you should be able to add some css similar to this:

```
    #container .yui3-widget-bd {background-color: red;}
```